# ServerSocket: Handling disconnection(s) from client

Tags: java, sockets, callback, event-handling, serversocket

**Requirement:**
I am writing a Java application where I need my application to act as a server listening on a specific port 'xxxx' for incoming connections over **TCP**. Once connected to the client, there will be a stream of bytes sent from the client that my application will process and appropriately save the information in the database. I **have been able** to achieve this functionality so far.

**Scenario to handle:** I need to handle one specific scenario (which might be rare, but still). The client-server connection may lapse at times owing to network conditions. In that case, I need my application to wait for the connection to re-establish and resume reading the stream of bytes from the client.

I am relatively new to socket programming in Java and am looking for viable solutions. Two possible solutions came into my mind (which may or may not be technically feasible):

1. ***Configuring a callback*** - I could configure a callback such that the readFromClient() method is initiated as soon as the connection is (re)established. I don't know how to go about this.
2. ***Adding an event listener*** - If connection to the client is considered an event, I could register an event listener and trigger the readFromClient() method as soon as the connection is (re)established. I have a basic idea on how to do this and am also trying to implement it. But would appreciate if someone can come up with a clean approach.

I don't know if I am thinking in the right direction. But I think these could be possible solutions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you use tcp or udp?

Comment: @Wufo - Sorry that I didn't mention this detail. I am using TCP.

Answer (score 0):

> ...**re-establish** and **resume reading** the stream...

The point is (in my understanding): There is no re-establish. If the connection is gone (IOException occurs) , there is no more to re-establish.

By using TCP, you don't need (or less) to care about network conditions.

If you want to know, whether a connection is alive, you have to use heartbeats.

If you want to reconnect to client, he must offer you the possibility.

Maybe I didnt get the point you're talking about, but you could post some code and show the error-situation (maybe some errors).